# recursive call on QuickSort algorithm

Tags: c#, recursion, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I have an array as `A[] = { 10, 5, 3, 9, 22, 24, 28, 27, 15 }`, I wanted to sort this Array using `QuickSort`. I have a method for quick sort as

```
QuickSort(int[] num, int start, int end)
{
   if(start < end)
   {
      int pIndex = Partition(num, start, end); //Pivot Index
      QuickSort(num, start, pIndex-1);
      QuickSort(num, pIndex + 1, end);
   }
}
```

Here, i am assuming the last index as the pivot element, i.e `15` is the first pivot element at first iteration.

For Partition:

```
public static int Partition(int[] arr, int start, int end)
{
    int pivot = arr[end];
    int i = start - 1;

    for (int j = start; j <= end - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            Swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }

    Swap(arr, i + 1, end);
    return i + 1;
}
```

As in the `QuickSort` i divide the problem into two sets, the first with all elements smaller or equal to the pivot, and the second with all elements larger than the pivot.

So, as making the left recursive call I get the output as

```
3 5 9 10 15 24 28 27 22

3 5 9 10 15 24 28 27 22

3 5 9 10 15 24 28 27 22
```

Now, my confusion is when after sorting the element on the left side, how the recursive call shift to right?

How the `pIndex + 1 = 5` i.e `QuickSort(num, pIndex + 1, end)` gets evaluated?

Why after the first right recursive call is made then the program does not evaluate to `QuickSort(num, start, pIndex-1)`.

Basically, How is recursive call working on the `QuickSort`?

Comment: `QuickSort` calls itself twice, `QuickSort(num, start, pIndex-1);` and `QuickSort(num, pIndex + 1, end);`. The first recurses on the left side, the second on the right, surely?

Comment: does it call at once or does it called after the left recursion has been done?

Comment: It calls after the left recursion is done. The first call recursive call to `QuickSort` must complete before the second call starts, and the first recursive call only completes after the full left recursion has been done.

Comment: how  in the right recursive call(when all left recursive is complete), it use the `Pivot Index as 5` and make, `QuickSort(num, 5, 8)`, because while evaluating the left recursive call the pivot has been changed and it has been moved to left most of the left array. and how when evaluating the right sets, the pivot start from the what was on the first call(before any recursion).

Comment: `pIndex`, `start` and `end` are local variables. When you call `QuickSort(num, start, pIndex-1)`, that passes *copies* of those values into the recursive call. When the second recursive call to `QuickSort(num, pIndex + 1, end);` is made, it uses the original unmodified copies. Thus the pivot hasn't been changed.

Comment: I recommend stepping through your code in a debugger. Use the Call Stack window to move between different recursive invocations of the `QuickSort` method. Hover over variables to inspect their current value.

Comment: i have been using VS studio debugger and watching the value, but i did not understand how it jump to next recursive call when  it evaluates the left call, with the  same value of the local variables which was at first before making any call.

Comment: C# is *pass-by-value* by default. When you pass a variable into a method, then a *copy* of that variable is passed. If the method assigns to that variable, that only changes the *copy*, and not the original variable in the calling method. (Note that with reference types, the reference itself is copied, but the copy references the same underlying object). This behaviour can be changed using `ref` and `out`.